# Linq Groupby issue not summing up

Tags: c#, linq

I am having a bit of problem in that I am trying to GroupBy using linq and although it works, it only works when I eliminate one element of the code.

```
nestedGroupedStocks = stkPositions.GroupBy(x => new { x.stockName,
                                     x.stockLongshort,x.stockIsin, x.stockPrice })
             .Select(y => new stockPos
             {
                 stockName = y.Key.stockName,
                 stockLongshort = y.Key.stockLongshort,
                 stockIsin = y.Key.stockIsin,
                 stockPrice = y.Key.stockPrice,
                 stockQuantity = y.Sum(x => x.stockQuantity)
             }).ToList();
```

The above code Groups my stock positions and the results in the list containing 47 entries but what it fails to do is sum duplicate stocks with different quantities...

```
nestedGroupedStocks = stkPositions.GroupBy(x => new { x.stockName,
                         x.stockIsin, x.stockPrice })
             .Select(y => new stockPos
             {
                 stockName = y.Key.stockName,
                 stockIsin = y.Key.stockIsin,
                 stockPrice = y.Key.stockPrice,
                 stockQuantity = y.Sum(x => x.stockQuantity)
             }).ToList();
```

However, if I elimanate "x.longshort" then I get the desired result, 34 stocks summed up, but the then all longshort elements in the list are null...

Its driving me nuts :-)

Answer (score 2):

This part

```
.GroupBy(x => new { x.stockName,x.stockLongshort,x.stockIsin, x.stockPrice })
```

is the problem. You are trying to group the elements by that new object as key, but x.stockLongshort will most likely change for every single element in the list, making the `GroupBy` fail unless the name and the stockLongshort will match in both elements ( as for the other 2 fields, but I assume those are always the same).

```
nestedGroupedStocks = stkPositions.GroupBy(x => x.stockName)
         .Select(y => new stockPos
         {
             stockName = y.First().stockName,
             stockLongshort = y.First().stockLongshort,
             stockIsin = y.First().stockIsin,
             stockPrice = y.First().stockPrice,
             stockQuantity = y.Sum(z => z.stockQuantity)
         }).ToList();
```

*Note that the stockLongshort property is set to be equal to the value of the first element in the group. You could set it to 0 if that's more usefull to you.*

**Longer Explanation**

GroupBy returns `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>` , that is, a "set" (that you can enumarte) of Groups, with each element of the same group sharing the same `Key`, that you have defined  with the lambda expression in the argument.

If you put x.stockLongshort as a property of the `Key` object, that becomes a discriminant of the evaluation made by `GroupBy`, that, as a consequence, puts two elements that differ just by that property in two distinct groups.

Comment: Thanks. That works a treat. Now I have understand why using your explanation!! Muchas Gracias

Comment: I have added some more text to make the expalantion more clear, at least I hope so :)